# user_signed_in? not working when change subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying some different with devise

overload the devise session controller

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => :failure)
    return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)                         
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    subdomain_name = current_user.account.subdomain_name
    if !current_account
      redirect_to root_url(:host => "#{subdomain_name}" + "." + "#{request.host}")
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end  
end
```

My Application Controller is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include UrlHelper
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :is_root_domain?
  before_filter :current_account

  def is_root_domain?
    # return true if there is no subdomain
    puts "++++++++++++++++++++++++++#{request.host_with_port}"
    (request.subdomains(0).present? && request.subdomains(0) != "www") ? false : true
    # request.subdomains.first.present? && request.subdomains.first != "www"
  end

  def current_account
    # If subdomain is present, returns the account, else nil
    if !is_root_domain?
      @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain_name(request.subdomains(0))      
      if @current_account.nil?
        flash[:notice] = "There is no Account with this subdomain"
        redirect_to root_url(:account => false)
      end
    else
      @current_account = nil
    end
    @current_account
  end  

end
```

And my application layout is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Subdomain</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        <% if is_root_domain? %>
          <h1>Sub<span class="off">Domain</span></h1>
        <% else %>
          <h1><%= @current_account.name %></h1>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <!--<div><%#=flash[:notice]%> <%#=flash[:alert]%></div>-->
      <div id="menu">
        <ul>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li class="menuitem"><a>Signed in as : <%= current_user.email %></a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
          <% end %>
          <% if !user_signed_in? %>
            <% if is_root_domain? %>
              <li class="menuitem"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Design</a></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></li>
            <% else %>
              <li class="menuitem"><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></li>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <div id="leftmenu">

          <div id="leftmenu_top"></div>

          <div id="leftmenu_main">

            <h3>Links</h3>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Ruby</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ajax</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Web design</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Web Programming</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">RAILS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Internet Marketing</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>


          <div id="leftmenu_bottom"></div>
        </div>
      <% end %>




      <div id="content">


        <div id="content_top"></div>
        <div id="content_main">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
        <div id="content_bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

now when I am trying to sign in from root means localhost it redirect to subdomain.localhost
but cannot signin for that domain

if I remove subdomain from subdomain.localhost:3000 it shows the user in his page 
i.e user already signin

user_signed_in? not working for subdomain

If I signin from a subdomain then all are working correctly.
But when I am trying to signin from root domain I got the error

Somebody please help me

Thanks in advance

Kausik

Comment: did you have a look at the cookie that is used for your session? is it applicable for the subdomain too?

Answer (score 0):

create the session table with "rails generate session_migration"

```
exampleapp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :domain => :all
```